# Creating a very complicated long table

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to create a complicated long table as in the figure below. I want to create it as a long table so that the heading of the table goes to a new page. The complicity is due to the merge of row and columns.

[image]
[image]

Please help me out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could start here:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a6paper, landscape]{geometry} % <-- A6 and landscape just to demonstrate repeating headers

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Attribute Group}     & \multicolumn{4}{l|}{Stuff}                                                                \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                     & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{This}                   & \multicolumn{2}{l|}{That}                   \\ \hline
\endhead
%
\multirow{2}{*}{1. Stuff}            & A                  & Lorem                  & C                  & Dolor                  \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                     & B                  & Ipsum                  & D                  & Sit                    \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{2. More Stuff}       & A                  & Tick                   & \multirow{2}{*}{C} & \multirow{2}{*}{Toe}   \\ \cline{2-3}
                                     & B                  & Tack                   &                    &                        \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{3. This never  ends} & A                  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Duck duck}                                       \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                     & B                  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Duck duck duck}                                  \\ \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{4. Alpha}            & A                  & Lorem                  & C                  & Dolor                  \\ \cline{2-5} 
                                     & B                  & Ipsum                  & D                  & Sit                    \\ \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{5. More ducks}       & A                  & Duck                   & \multirow{4}{*}{E} & \multirow{4}{*}{Duck}  \\ \cline{2-3}
                                     & B                  & Duck                   &                    &                        \\ \cline{2-3}
                                     & C                  & Duck                   &                    &                        \\ \cline{2-3}
                                     & D                  & Duck                   &                    &                        \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{6. Omega}            & A                  & Stuff                  & \multirow{3}{*}{D} & \multirow{3}{*}{Hello} \\ \cline{2-3}
                                     & B                  & Stuff                  &                    &                        \\ \cline{2-3}
                                     & C                  & Stuff                  &                    &                        \\ \hline
\multirow{3}{*}{7. Stuff}            & \multirow{3}{*}{A} & \multirow{3}{*}{Stuff} & B                  & Stuff                  \\ \cline{4-5} 
                                     &                    &                        & C                  & Stuff                  \\ \cline{4-5} 
                                     &                    &                        & D                  & Stuff                  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]